# NLTK ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

I should train the model to determine gender of a name.
I made the list like

> [['Friedtic', 'Homer'], ['Alice', 'Miranda']]

I tried

```
classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_data)
```

but there is the error

> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Answer (score 1):

You need to structure your data into tuple items. Additionally, every item in your train set needs a label which tells the classifier to what class the name belongs. Finally, you need features that contain information on how to identify a name's (supposed) 'gender'.

[The NLTK tutorials](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch06.html) show how to structure your items, right under **Gender Identification**.

I could show you how, but this is quite clearly how the developers intended it.